# Why doesn't archive.ubuntu.com use HTTPS?

Tags: apt, https, official-repositories, add-apt-repository

I always see instructions for adding the Universe and Multiverse repositories that look something like the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main universe restricted multiverse"
```

Recently I tried editing this to use HTTPS instead and was dismayed to find that archive.ubuntu.com doesn't appear to respond to HTTPS. Now I wonder how feasible it would be, or what damage could be done, if an attacker were to successfully perform a man-in-the-middle attack here?

Am I being too paranoid, considering the role these repositories perform on a system?